# Object Lag behind Mouse

Tags: vb.net

Label1 below moves right and left. How would I get it to lag and "catchup" to the mouse pointer?

```
Private xpos as integer = 10 

    Private Sub me_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint



        Dim lbl As New label
        lbl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(xpos, 100)

        end sub 

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        lbl1.Location = New Point(MyPictureBox.PointToClient(New Point(MousePosition.X, 0)).X, 100)
```

Comment: looks like the label movement is tied to the timer not the mouse.  what is the timer interval?

Comment: The interval of the timer is 60.

Comment: that is just about as fast as the timer can go (reliably), if you want the label to chase the mouse, better to use a mouse move event